# modify array multi-dimensional symfony

Tags: arrays, symfony

I'm getting very confused when working with array/multi-dimensional array. I know the basics stuff but I cannot get to work the following example:

```
"hello":{
  "id":100,
  "items":[
     {
        "a":3,
        "b":1,
        "c":2
     }
  ]
}
```

And my code:

```
public function createHello()
{
    $collection = $this->greetings->getItems();

    $hello = [
        'id'=> $this->getId(),
        'items' => [
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($collection as $col) {
        $hello['items'][]['a'] = $this->getValue($col);
    }

    return $hello;
}
```

And this is what is displayed:

```
hello:{
 "id": 100,
 "items": [
    [],
    {
       "a": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

How to resolve this? I'm continue switching the values and the definition of the array but with no help. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found myself the solution:

```
public function createHello()
{
    $collection = $this->greetings->getItems();
    $hello = [ 
       'id'=> $this->getId(),
    ];

    foreach ($collection as $col) {
        $hello['items'][] = $this->getItems($col);
    }

    return $hello;
}


public function getItems($col)
{
    $a = ..;
    $b = ..;
    $c = ..;
    $items = [
        'a' => $a,
        'b' => $b,
        'c' => $c
    ]

    return $items;
}
```